# Firestore `addDoc()` function seems to resolve before the doc is created

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with Firestore Web SDK v9 in an NodeJS environment. I do not use the live update but query data when needed.

My data is held in a local variable `entries`. After creating new entry in the Firestore collection `entries`, I try fetch all docs from this collection to update the local variable. But the newly added entry does not show up:

```js
/// scaffolding:

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, getDocs, query } from "firebase/firestore"

const app = initializeApp({
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
})
const db = getFirestore(app)


/// payload:

let entries = []

try {

  // add doc to collection:

  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "entries"), { foo: "bar" })
  console.log(docRef.id) // will print the id as expected
  
  // fetch all docs in collection:

  const q = query(collection(db, "entries")
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)

  const result = []
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    result.push({
      _id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data()
    })
  }
  entries = result // this will only contain the docs that have already existed BEFORE the addDocs() operation above

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error) // no error is being logged, so the above seems to work as expected
}
```

If I add a timeout of a couple of seconds between the add doc and fetch docs section, the local `entries` variable is populated as expected:

```js
// add doc section

await new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve()
  }, 5000)
})

// fetch docs section

entries = result // will contain the newly created doc along with those that have already existed
```

I am confused by this behavior as [the documentation for `addDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#adddoc) states that the function will resolve **after the newly created doc has been written to the backend**:

> Returns:
>
> Promise<DocumentReference>
>
> A Promise resolved with a DocumentReference pointing to the newly created document after it has been written to the backend (Note that it won't resolve while you're offline).

My app (it's running in the browser) is clearly online, and if it would be offline, the Promise should not resolve at all.

Does Firebase take additional time to process the new document? How can I wait for it to be available?

---

Edit: the issue I described above was with the real Firestore environment. But the same thing happenes whe I run tests in the Firestore emulator as well:

```js
import {
    initializeTestEnvironment,
    assertFails,
    assertSucceeds,
} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing"

import {
    doc,
    getDoc,
    setDoc,
    updateDoc,
    deleteDoc
} from "firebase/firestore"

import fs from "fs"
import path from "path"

import "mocha"

const PROJECT_ID = "workmatefinder-dev-7f1a5"

let testEnv

describe("Reading groups", () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
            projectId: PROJECT_ID,
            firestore: {
                host: "127.0.0.1",
                port: "8080",
                rules: fs.readFileSync(new URL(path.join(import.meta.url, "./firestore.rules")), "utf-8")
            }
        })

        await testEnv.withSecurityRulesDisabled(async (context) => {
            await setDoc(doc(context.firestore(), "groups", "alices"), {
                name: "alice's group",
                ownerId: "alice",
                members: [ "alice" ]
            })
        })
    })

    it("user is allowed to read groups", async () => {
        const dbBob = testEnv.authenticatedContext("bob").firestore()
        await assertSucceeds(getDoc(doc(dbBob, "groups", "alices")))
    })

    afterEach(async () => {
        await testEnv.clearFirestore()
    })
})
```

This occasionally (but not all the time) fails with `FirebaseError: false for 'get' @ Lx, Null value error. for 'get' @ Ly`.

If I add this at the end of `beforeEach`, the error is gone:

```js
        // to avoid "null value errors" (which means that the above "awaits" don't work)
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve()
            }, 1000)
        })
```

So it's again the same issue, that `setDoc` does seem to resolve before the document is actually created.

Comment: Your code is adding to and fetching from different collections.  "entries" is not the same as "groups".

Comment: oh, my bad, thanks for the heads up. But that was just an issue with creating a reduced example form my original code. The original code fetches from the right collection and the result contains all the expected documents _except_ the newly created one.

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide the actual [complete minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue instead of copying some that kinda looks like it, or parts redacted.  That way we can copy it back and try it ourselves. Reproducibility is important, and I can't tell you how many times the redacted code was the problem after all.

Comment: Ok thx. Is there any quick way to provide a Firebase backend for someone who doesn't have an account?

Comment: If there is a reason for this behavior by design, someone who knows Firestore better than me should be able to point me to where the behavior is documented. This is what I'm asking for, nothing more. If it is a bug in Firestore, I don't think that SO is the right place to debug it. I'd rather discuss it in some GitHub then. You seem to be the specialist here. Can you enlighten me please how Firestore handles the creation of documents behind the scenes? Anything that could explain this? Or a better way to approach this to not have this issue?

Comment: The behavior you're observing should not happen, but we really need to see the reproduction code to see if you might be doing something wrong. We don't need a whole backend set up, just instructions on what to do to reproduce it.

Comment: So I added the scaffolding, but this is not the point because everything works fine except that querying a collection right after `setDoc` or `addDoc` does not return what I would expect after reading the documentation about said functions and I found no clue anywhere what is happening here.

Comment: If this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74757053/10043870 Querying the new doc directly works fine but querying it as part of a collection does not work. IDK what is happening here.

Comment: We still can't see what you're doing to observe the contents of `entires` and what exactly it contains that's different than what you expect. We also can't see how you are invoking this code.  Certainly it is not just sitting as the main content of some source file.  Are you calling a method or function that contains this code? How? And how does that relate to the code that observes `entries` is showing the unexpected result? Have you tried step-through debugging of this code to examine values more closely?

Comment: "After creating new entry in the Firestore collection entries, I try fetch all docs from this collection to update the local variable. But the newly added entry does not show up". As I have described, this is what happens: the newly created entry is not part of the result set. If I do the query a couple of seconds later, it suddenly is.

Comment: Nothing happens in between those two operations on my side. I really don't know how my whole code will help you explain this. It is a timing issue between `setDoc` and querying the collection that this doc was created in.

Comment: If you would just read what I write between the code examples, you would know everything you need.

Comment: I can't help you without being able to reproduce exactly what you've done.  As I said, I don't immediately see that there is a problem, but also I can't see the whole thing in such a way that I can observe the same results exactly as you do.  It's up to you.

Comment: OK, do you have an example for such a "complete minimal code" that shows a similar case with Firebase so I know what you expect? I don't think that dropping my whole VueJS app into SO will help anyone and the repo is (and will stay) private anyways, so this won't even be an option.

Comment: Create a new, minimal vue project with only the code that performs the query.  Include in your description what you are doing to invoke that code, and how you are observing the result.  Common observations are logs (show your logging code too) and step-through debugging - we need to be able to do the same thing and see the same result.  Be sure to include in your question what you expect the result to be, and be clear how what you are observing is different than that.  This might require including the contents of the database as a starting point, which we could also reproduce.

Comment: If you are unable to repro in this way, then we can only conclude that the problem is elsewhere in your project in code or processes that we can't see and haven't been described.  This situation is actually quite common, which is why we often call of minimal complete examples - this reduces the number of moving parts and focuses completely on a single specific bit of code at hand.

Comment: So here's an example now. The same thing happens in prod as well as in testing with the Firestore emulator. I'm very positive now, that there's a bug in the library or an error in the docs.

Comment: `getDoc` and `getDocs` will fall back to the local cache if the server is unavailable/not ready. What behaviour do you get when you force data to be collected from the server only? (using [`getDocFromServer`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#getdocfromserver) and [`getDocsFromServer`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#getdocsfromserver) respectively)

Comment: If you're now positive that there's a bug, the next step is to file that on GitHub with your repro steps, being clear which client library version you're using. Note that the emulator is nowhere near the same code that runs in production. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not sure why is that exactly happening but you can avoid this behavior by using [onSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) feature on your collection like this:

```js
import { onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
```

```js
const unsub = onSnapshot(collection(db, "groups"), (querySnapshot) => {
  console.log("Updated Docs: ", querySnapshot.docChanges);
  console.log("Docs: ", querySnapshot.docs);
});
```

By doing this, you can be informed whenever your docs on that collection being changed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do I understand correctly that `onSnapshot` will fire whenever there is any change to a collection? If I listen to the collection, I can't be sure that it fires because of the doc the current user has created or if some other user did something that created a new snapshot. Will the timing be right if I listen to the docRef that was returned by `addDoc()` or is the snapshot already created when the docRef is being returned?

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant way to do this, which circumvents the issue completely, is to just push the object that was written to the doc to the local array:

```js
let entries = []

const newEntry = { foo: "bar" }
await addDoc(collection(db, "entries"), newEntry)

entries.push(newEntry)
```

Another way that - surprisingly! - works is to not fetch the whole collection but only the newly created doc:

```js
const entries = []

const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "entries"), { foo: "bar" });
const docSnapshot = await getDoc(docRef);
        
entries.push(docSnapshot.data());
```

I don't know why this works (while fetching the whole collection right after creating the doc will not return that doc as part of the result), but it works ...